# Get HTTP Header on Redirect Angular 6

Tags: angular, http-headers

How do I get the `onNgInit()` or other method to receive the http header after a redirect to my site from another source? For example, an authentication tokende that I need to validate

Answer (score 0):

Angular has the "HttpInterceptor" for that use case, see the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) for more info.
With the interceptor you are able to read and modify the headers. You can check this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/@vigneshsithirai/angular-6-7-http-client-interceptor-with-error-handling) to get an impression of how to use it.